# Central limit theorem used in a scenario where the sampling is not random

Tags: confidence-interval, central-limit-theorem

I am working on an online course of statistics. The exercise is shown below. My feeling is that the exercise has a defect: The sampling is on 114 pregnant women who smoke, whereas the population is all pregnant women. So, it seems to me applying the central limit theorem does not make sense. Do I misunderstand something?

[image]

Comment: You're trying to compare the population mean pregnancy length of women who smoke during pregnancy with a specified numeric value.

Comment: Thanks. In the problem statement, the standard deviation regards the general pregnant women population.  That info does not look helpful. It should have been the standard deviation of pregnant women who smoke, if you want to apply CLT.  Am I right?

Comment: You would need to consider whether it might be reasonable to make an assumption that the standard deviation is not substantively changed -- that the impact of being in the smoking group (compared to the available figure) might affect the mean but not the standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

The exercise itself looks problematic: it makes an implicit assumption that the population standard deviation (pregnancy length of all women) is the same as that of a particular subset (pregnancy length of all women who smoke).